# Expandable ListView children not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

It's like they aren't there at all. It compiles, but there's nothing visible nor selectable in each group. here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my Activity class. The inflated xml for the children have barely much in there at all.

```
package com.anthonyce.mcathomie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayoptionsActivity extends Activity {
ExpandableListView Mtopics;
ExpandableAdapter MtopicsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playoptions);
    //set up adapter
    MtopicsAdapter = new ExpandableAdapter();
    Mtopics = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.mtopicsListView);
    Mtopics.setAdapter(MtopicsAdapter);
    //Mtopics.setGroupIndicator(null);
}

public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names",
        "Fish Names" };
private String[][] children = { { "Arnold" }, { "Ace" }, { "Fluffy" },
        { "Goldy" } };

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final class ExpandChildRow extends LinearLayout {
            public ExpandChildRow(Context context) {
                super(context);
                LayoutInflater childInflate = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout childView = (LinearLayout) childInflate.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_childrow, this, true);

                TextView childtxt = (TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicchildtext);
                childtxt.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            }
        }

        ExpandChildRow ChildRow = new ExpandChildRow(getBaseContext());
        return ChildRow;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final class ExpandGroupRow extends LinearLayout {
            public ExpandGroupRow(Context context) {
                super(context);
                LayoutInflater groupInflate = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout groupView = (LinearLayout) groupInflate.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_grouprow, this, true);

                TextView grouptxt = (TextView)groupView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicgrouptext);
                grouptxt.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            }
        }

        ExpandGroupRow GroupRow = new ExpandGroupRow(getBaseContext());
        return GroupRow;

    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, i'm so noob. the reason it was acting up was because the checkbox being anywhere on the group row was conflicting with the group divider or something of the sort. Maybe the group divider actually is a checkbox itself. I simply removed the checkbox and everything was working again. I suppose my layout xml file needs revision.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with  this: `class ExpandGroupRow extends LinearLayout`
You are trying to use this class as a UI element but you are not setting up the layout params for `this` in the constructor.
It might be easier to just use the LinearLayout that is returned by the inflater instead of this class. Something like:

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater groupInflate = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout groupView = (LinearLayout) groupInflate.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_grouprow, parent, false);

            TextView grouptxt = (TextView)groupView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicgrouptext);
            grouptxt.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return groupView;

}
```

Comment: thanks for assisting. honestly, i'd love to do it like that too, but i get errors with context if i do it like that. i'm not confident that I can set up the constructors w/ the context properly. i am indeed a beginner

Comment: oh, just replacing `context` with `getBaseContext()` in the above code should work.